# Need to get count of array items in my dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I created a dictionary with the key of type string and the values of type string[]. i am having a hard time figuring out how to get the count of the array in the dict. so i know dict.count returns the number of dictionary pairs but not sure how to get the count of the array

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> csvFileNameSheetName = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

i tried this but obviously wont work

```
 for (int idx = 0; idx < csvFileNameSheetName.Values.Count; idx++)
```

what i need is something like `csvFilenameSheetName.values.Values.count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Linq's [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0) to put all the `string[]` items into a single enumeration:

```
csvFileNameSheetName.SelectMany(kvp=>kvp.Value).Count(); //using System.Linq
```

Or for better performance you can use [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-6.0) to add up the counts:

```
csvFileNameSheetName.Sum(kvp=>kvp.Value.Length); //using System.Linq
```

Comment: Why are you using Value instead of Values?

Comment: Values doesn't exist in a KeyValuePair.

Comment: @Hogan They are equivalent. `dict.Values.Sum(v=>v.Length)` is equivalent to `dict.Sum(kvp=>kvp.Value.Length)`. So no reason really. If I had to pick one `Values` seems slightly cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Use linq

```
int c = csvFileNameSheetName.Aggregate(0, (r, i) => r = r +  i.Value.Count());
```

Comment: yep, this is perfectly correct.

Comment: thanks @CodeReaper -- I also appreciate you coping it for your answer and imitation is the sincerest form of flattery

Comment: linq is kind of my thing. :) there is only one way you can write an `aggregate`. Like I can also say that the `SelectMany` variation by @Nigel Bess will cause memory allocations as it tries to flatten the Dictionary. I would not use that.

Comment: @CodeReaper -- true, the select many solution is the worst

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = csvFileNameSheetName.Aggregate(0, (r, kvp) => r = r + kvp.Value.Count());
```

OR

```
var count = 0;
foreach(var strArr in csvFileNameSheetName.Values)
{
    count += strArr.Length;      
}
```